# ¿Cómo valido una contraseña hasheada con este código php?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Inicialmente tenía este código que validaba un usuario y una contraseña:

```
require_once "conn.php";
function validUser(&$error){
if((!isset($_POST['user'])) || (!isset($_POST['pass']))){
    $error[0] = "Usuario y/o contraseña incorrectos.";
    return null;
}
$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
if(($user == '') || ($pass == '')){
    $error[0] = "Usuario y/o contraseña incorrectos.";
    return null;
}else{

    $con = connection();
    $sql = "SELECT name FROM usuarios WHERE name = :user AND password = :pass";
    $query = $con->prepare($sql);
    $query-> bindParam(':user', $user);
    $query-> bindParam(':pass', $pass);
    $query-> execute();
    $contador = $query -> rowCount();
    if($contador != 1){
        $error[0] = "Usuario y/o contraseña incorrectos.";
        return null;
    }
    $con = null;
    return $user;
}
}
```

Ahora en la base de datos guardo una contraseña, que con otra función, se inserta hasheada. ¿Como aplico ahora en este código la función password_verify()?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mira tenes que traerte la contraseña hasheada y luego compararla por php.
Para eso vas a tener que modificar tu query de:

`"SELECT name FROM usuarios WHERE name = :user AND password = :pass";`

a

`"SELECT name, password FROM usuarios WHERE name = :user;`

Una vez que tengas tu **password** hasheada, ahi vas a tener que comparar con la funcion que pedis **(password_verify)** el input del usuario en el login y el hash.

Te paso como quedaria todo el codigo:

```
<?php
    require_once "conn.php";

    function validUser(&$error)
    {
        if ((!isset($_POST['user'])) || (!isset($_POST['pass']))) {
            $error[0] = "Usuario y/o contraseña incorrectos.";
            return null;
        }

        $user = $_POST['user'];
        $pass = $_POST['pass'];

        if (($user == '') || ($pass == '')) {

            $error[0] = "Usuario y/o contraseña incorrectos.";
            return null;

        } else {

            $con   = connection();
            $sql   = "SELECT name, password FROM usuarios WHERE name = :user";
            $query = $con->prepare($sql);
            $query->bindParam(':user', $user);
            $query->execute();

            $resultado = $query->fetch(); // Supongo que haras un fetch_assoc
            $contador = $query -> rowCount();
            if($contador != 1){
                $error[0] = "Usuario y/o contraseña incorrectos.";
                return null;
            }

            if (!password_verify($pass, $resultado['password'])) {
                $error[0] = "Usuario y/o contraseña incorrectos.";
                return null;
            }

            $con = null;

            return $user;
        }
    }
```

Espero haber sido de ayuda

Abrazo!